# what is the best practice create reports in SSRS with breaking down same data all possible ways?

Tags: sql-server, performance, reporting-services, ssms

I need to create SSRS report where user need to look at the data many different ways(grouping, comparing etc). Using Visual Studio 2010. SQL server 2012.

I am using one stored procedure for that, dumping data into cte and from there doing all grouping.

My question is:
Is any way I can dump data from one stored procedure into #TempTable, then from that #TempTable into multiple views (grouping the way I need), and then in SSRS query that data from different views (use datasets as view).

Something like that:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcName
    (   
        @DateFrom datetime, 
        @DateTo datetime
    )
AS
BEGIN

CREATE #TempTable 
INSERT INTO #TempTable
SELECT  Col1,
        Col2,
        Col3,
        col4...
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2

CREATE VIEW MyView1
AS
SELECT  Col1,
        Col2
GROUP BY Col1
FROM    #TempTable

CREATE VIEW MyView2
AS
SELECT  Col3,
        Col4
GROUP BY Col3
FROM    #TempTable

CREATE VIEW MyView3
AS
SELECT  Col1,
        Col4
GROUP BY Col2
FROM    #TempTable

END -- End of SP 
GO
```

And what would be the BEST way in terms of performance to create reports where user need to bread down  the data all possible ways?
Right now I am trying to do every calculation in SSMS, then bring this data in SSRS. Performance is good, but sometimes I have up to 100 columns. It gets messy.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a good way to do it. I've done something similar before and passed in a lot of parameters from the report to the dataset. These parameters were used to build up dynamic sql so I had full control over grouping sorting etc but it is messy. To be honest SSRS is not really the bets tool for this. If you  are not tied to SSRS then look at other alternatives, PowerBI can very quickly create matrix reports which would do the job.

Comment: I dont think company is going to pay for something like that

Comment: There is a free version

Comment: @Oleg what you want is a cube.

Comment: @Canadean_AS So can PowerBI work with stored procedures and have parameters that end user will be able to choose?
Thanks

Comment: It's not quite the same as SSRS in that respect. You can have direct queries and I think you can use SP's from there (I haven't checked). Parameters are actually slicers, so yo can filter data. As @Snowlockk suggested, you actually need a cube to do what you want (SQL Server Analysis Services) but you'll still need some way of building a report. You can use Excel to connect to a cube as a pivot table and maybe use that for your report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, SSRS is not a very dynamic environment. It's difficult to predict every way a used will want to breakout the data. So my suggestion would be to offer a PowerPivot of the data in Excel as an alternative. That way, they can easily add and remove row/column groupings and see the subtotals. The slicers are also very handy.

More specifically to your question, I think in general the best practice would be to let the stored procedure just return all the raw data. SSRS is very good at grouping and sorting the data. That will put less strain on the server and require slightly more processing time. Of course, if you reach a point where there's just too much to process at run-time, you'll have to re-balance that workload or get more resources allocated.

Sometimes you have to get creative. For example, I have a report with almost 300 columns and over 100K rows. Normally it would take over 10 minutes to run or to export. So I turned on caching and scheduled a subscription to export it as a .csv each day. That way the data is available to open in Excel and the report is quick to re-run throughout the day.